# Удалить все элементы с классом, который содержит ..._ru | JS

Tags: javascript, классы, list, delete, indexof

Есть небольшой одностраничник. Нужно через js удалить все элементы с классом которые содержат ..._ru. Например есть список `<ul><li>`... именно оттуда нужно отыскать те эл. с классом. Но в дальнейшем понадобиться удалить те элементы, с указанным классом, во всей странице. Лучше уж показать тот пример, который чекает всю страницу и удаляет те классы (все равно стр маленькая, по оптимизации не ударит).

P.S: Пробовал через jquery, а именно функцию .each() и indexOf() отыскать, но индекс элемента некорректный, чтобы достучаться до него.

```
<ul>
    <li class="service1_en">Washing</li>
    <li class="service2_en">Cleaning</li>
    <li class="service1_ru">Доставка</li>
    <li class="service3_en">Cargo</li>
    <li class="service2_ru">Сервировка</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать `document.querySelectorAll`. Селектор: `[class$=_ru]` Выбирает все элементы со значением атрибута `class`, **заканчивающимся** на `«_ru»`. Можете ознакомится с некоторыми примерами селекторов здесь https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.php?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[class$=_ru]").forEach(e => {
  e.remove()
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="service1_en">Washing</li>
  <li class="service2_en">Cleaning</li>
  <li class="service1_ru">Доставка</li>
  <li class="service3_en">Cargo</li>
  <li class="service2_ru">Сервировка</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('li[class*="_ru"]').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="service1_en">Washing</li>
    <li class="service2_en">Cleaning</li>
    <li class="service1_ru">Доставка</li>
    <li class="service3_en">Cargo</li>
    <li class="service2_ru">Сервировка</li>
</ul>
```

Использован данные по CSS селекторам, а именно звёздочка

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors